# Cython Class, create NumPy with Zeros

Tags: python, performance, numpy, optimization, cython

i am trying to create a cython class which creates a NumPy with zeros. Later i want to write float values in that Numpy...
My python class looks like this:

```
class test:
    def __init__(self, b):
       self.b = b
       self.eTest = np.zeros((100, 100))
```

My cython class looks like this so far:

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
FTYPE = np.float
ctypedef np.float_t FTYPE_t
cdef class test:
   def __init__(self, b):
      cdef np.ndarray[FTYPE_t, ndim=2, mode='c'] eTest   <<<works fine without this line
      self.eTest = np.zeros((100,100), dtype=FTYPE)
```

My cython code doesn't work so far. I am struggling with the question how to create a NumPy of zeros (100, 100) without any Python. Is that even possible? I am not really familiar in cython, i am sorry if i am asking some really trivial questions!

Many thanks for all your help and advices!

Comment: When you say it "doesn't work", what exactly happens?

Comment: i get a CompileError, so i guess something is wrong with the way i write the class?!

Comment: It is generally quite useful if you tell us **what** compiler error you get.

Comment: CompileError: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redefine your class::

```
  cdef class test:
  cdef double[:,:] eTest
  def __init__(self, b):
      cdef np.ndarray[FTYPE_t, ndim=2, mode='c'] tmp
      tmp = np.zeros((100,100), dtype=FTYPE)
      self.eTest = tmp
```

Your ndarray (`tmp` in this case) can only be local to a function (the constructor in this case), so you should declare first `eTest` as a buffer-supporting type (a memoryview in my example) and then copy the ndarray to it.

As a side comment, I would directly assign the zeros ndarray to `eTest`:

```
cdef class test:
      cdef double[:,:] eTest
      def __init__(self, b):
          self.eTest =  np.zeros((100,100), dtype=FTYPE)
```

But I kept your structure in case you needed it.